# PHP PregMatch Error with spaces on extract

Tags: php, regex, expression

I want to extract data from a web source but i am getting error in preg match

```
    <?php

$html=file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/p/BJz4_yijmdJ/?taken-by=the.witty");
preg_match("("instapp:owner_user_id" content="(.*)")", $html, $match);
$title = $match[1];

echo $title;
?>
```

This is the error i get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'instapp' (T_STRING) in
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.php on line 4

Please help me how can i do this? and i also want to extract more data from the page with regex so is it possible to extract all at once using single code? or i want to use pregmatch many times?

Comment: what is `instapp:owner_user_id`? is it a literal?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: `preg_match('~"instapp:owner_user_id" content="([^"]*)"~', $html, $match);`

Comment: Thank you soo much.It worked @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: i want to extract     <meta property="al:ios:url" content="instagram://media?id=1329656989202933577" />
 ID too.is it possible to extract this too at same time i extract user id?  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Do you mean you want to get `1329656989202933577` and `instagram://media?id=1329656989202933577`?

Comment: i want to get 1329656989202933577 .as extracted. so a total of two extractions.the first one is in the above code .and this one.so i can get two extractions at same time with different varibles because later i have to concatenate those so please make them into different variables :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you did not form a valid string literal. Note that PHP supports both single- and double-quoted string literals, and you may use that to your advantage:

```
preg_match('~"instapp:owner_user_id" content="([^"]*)"~', $html, $match);
```

While it is OK to use paired `(...)` symbols as regex delimiters, I'd suggest using a more conventional `/` or `~`/`@` symbols.

Also, `(.*)` is a too generic pattern that may match more than you need since `.` also matches `"` and `*` is a greedy modifier, a negated character class is better, `([^"]*)`  - 0+ chars other than `"`.

**HOWEVER**, to parse HTML in PHP, you may use a DOM parser, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Here is a sample to get all `meta` tags that have `content` attribute and extracting the value of that attribute and saving in an array:

```
$html = "<html><head><meta property=\"al:ios:url\" content=\"instagram://media?id=1329656989202933577\" /></head><body><span/></body></html>";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$metas = $xpath->query('//meta[@content]');
$res = array();
foreach($metas as $m) { 
   array_push($res, $m->getAttribute('content'));
}
print_r($res);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OehvCj)

And to only get the `id` in the `content` attribute value of a `meta` tag whose `property` attribute is equal to `al:ios:url`, use

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$metas = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="al:ios:url"]');
$id = "";
if (preg_match('~[?&]id=(\d+)~', $metas->item(0)->getAttribute('content'), $match))
{
    $id = $match[1];
}
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ZkDFG6)

Comment: Thanks it worked.actually i am a total noob.i just started with learnin PHP and wanted to do this as i had work for this.i wanted to extract more data from the same page.can u please help me extract these two data ?

    <meta property="instapp:owner_user_id" content="3469066161" />
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="instagram://media?id=1329656989202933577" />

from the page https://www.instagram.com/p/BJz4_yijmdJ/?taken-by=the.witty

Comment: See https://ideone.com/LnhF8M. Actually, I do not understand what you exactly need, but that is already not related to this question.

Comment: its soo hard for me to understart DOM based.can u just make a simple one like u made above?
like this

 preg_match('~"instapp:owner_user_id" content="([^"]*)"~', $html, $match);

just make  a simple line like this that will extract 1329656989202933577 from that page [the value is dynamic]

view-source:https://www.instagram.com/p/BJz4_yijmdJ/?taken-by=the.witty

Comment: Well, try `if (preg_match('~"instapp:owner_user_id" content="[^\d"]*(\d+)"~', $html, $match)) {  $my_required_val = $match[1]; }`

Comment: you are still not getting it

    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="instagram://media?id=1329656989202933577" />

just extract 1329656989202933577 .make a regex that will extract 1329656989202933577 from the above code

Comment: Replace `instapp:owner_user_id` with `al:ios:url` in the above regex. See https://regex101.com/r/HXKYyJ/1

Comment: Thank you soo much.It worked.MY work is finally done :D thansk bro